# Solve the system of differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I plan on adding more into later just a bit stuck, researching it at the moment.

> Solve the system of differential equations
>   $$\begin{bmatrix} x'\\y' \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} -11&15\\ -30&31 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x\\y \end{bmatrix}= e^t\begin{bmatrix} 18\\30 \end{bmatrix}$$

Also what is the expected form of the answer for these questions?

Comment: what are $15'$ and $18'?$

Comment: If $15'=0$ then this is pretty easy to solve as the first equation is decoupled from the second.

Comment: Sorry typo i was copying the same latex code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$D$ is derivative wrt $t$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 D & 0 \\
 0 & D \\
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 x \\
 y \\
\end{array}
\right)-\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -11 & 15 \\
 -30 & 31 \\
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 x \\
 y \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 18 e^t \\
 30 e^t \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Combine LHS:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 D+11 & -15 \\
 30 & D-31 \\
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 x \\
 y \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 18 e^t \\
 30 e^t \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Use Cramer's rule:

$$x=\frac{\text{Det} \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 18 e^t & -15 \\
 30 e^t & D-31 \\
\end{array}
\right)}{\text{Det} \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 D+11 & -15 \\
 30 & D-31 \\
\end{array}
\right)}$$

$$(D^2-20 D+109)x=D18e^t-11\times 31e^t+15\times 30 e^t=-90e^t$$

$$x''-20x'+109x=-90e^t$$

Solution for x:

$$c_1 e^{10 t} \sin (3 t)+c_2 e^{10 t} \cos (3 t)-e^t$$

Do the same for y:

$$y=\frac{\text{Det} \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 D+11 & 18 e^t \\
 30 & 30 e^t \\
\end{array}
\right)}{\text{Det} \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 D+11 & -15 \\
 30 & D-31 \\
\end{array}
\right)}$$

The answer you will get is:

$$c_3 e^{10 t} \sin (3 t)+c_4 e^{10 t} \cos (3 t)-2 e^t$$

The $D$'s in the determinant of the numerator operates on the inhomogeneous terms, The $D$'s in the determinant of the numerator operates on x or y.

The homogeneous solutions of constant coefficient systems are the same (the constants $c$ will not be the same )

Comment: Use eigen vectors i mean

Comment: Too late now... You should have though of that earlier....